# How to send ping packets using jabber-net library

Tags: c#, xmpp, openfire

I am developing a xmpp client application. I need to send ping iq packets to the xmpp server to make sure the server is still alive. How can i send it thru jabber-net library ?
thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918099/how-do-i-send-a-ping-to-a-user-xmpp-which-method-do-i-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [FAQ_Packets](https://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/wiki/FAQ_Packets) and [XEP-0199](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0199.html).  Set NS to `urn:xmpp:ping`.  Something like:

```
namespace your.protocol
{
  public class PingQuery : Element
  {
    public const string PING_NS  = "urn:xmpp:ping";

    // used when creating elements to send
    public PingQuery(XmlDocument doc) : base("ping", PING_NS, doc)
    {}

    // used to create elements for inbound protocol
    public PingQuery(string prefix, XmlQualifiedName qname, XmlDocument doc)
        : base(prefix, qname, doc)
    {}
  }

  public class Factory : jabber.protocol.IPacketTypes
  {
    private static QnameType[] s_qnt = new QnameType[]
    {
      new QnameType("ping", PingQuery.PING_NS, typeof(your.protocol.PingQuery))
    };
    QnameType[] IPacketTypes.Types { get { return s_qnt; } }
  }
}
```

Then use something like:

```
private void jabberClient_OnStreamInit(object sender, ElementStream stream)
{
  stream.AddFactory(new your.protocol.Factory());
}
```

to hook in your factory.  Then use `IQTracker` as usual to send the request and get notified of the response.